# Pandas specific plot

Tags: pandas, dataframe, heatmap

I have a pandas df in the form of

```
            cell1 cell2 cell3
            1     Nan Nan        
Cell1       Nan   3   Nan    
Cell2       3     Nan 2   
Cell3       2     3   Nan    
Cell4       Nan   2   3
Cell5       3     1   Nan
```

1. I want to put in a plot like the format in the picture (some kind of a heatmap?). Not necessarily exactly the same, just the same concept
2. Each value has its own color (for example, 1=red, 2=yellow, 3=blue, NaN=white), changing the brightness/fading by the value, adding black outline to the cell by value
3. if it's possible I'd love the columns name to be below and rotated. (and also if possible, without seeing the number in the cell, just the color)

the plot format

[image]

I've looked at packages like seaborn and style but didn't manage to do it, maybe I did colored the cells, who knows, but I didn't manage to preform the plot so I can see it, I'd appreciate every kind of help

Comment: `import seaborn as sns; sns.heatmap(df)`

Answer (score 0):

Importing the packages to be used:

```py
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
```

First, you need to convert all the NaN values to a 0 in your pandas dataframe.

```py
df = df.replace(np.nan, 0)
```

You need a colormap to map the values to colors starting with 0. You can create a colormap using the `matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap` class. You can change the colors as you wish.

```py
cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["white","red","yellow","blue"])
```

Then, you can draw the heatmap using the `seaborn.heatmap` function. We will avoid the `annot` attribute to avoid displaying the values in the cells.

```py
sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap, linewidths=0.5, linecolor='black', annot=True, fmt='')
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, if you want to draw the heatmap without the color axis, you can set the `cbar` attribute to `False`. Instead you can add a legend with specific colors for each value to the plot.

```py
legend = ['1', '2', '3']
colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
patches = [mpatches.Patch(color=colors[i], label=legend[i]) for i in range(len(legend))]
sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap, linewidths=0.5, linecolor='black', annot=True, fmt='', cbar=False)
plt.legend(handles=patches, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```